# Calculate time between thresholds

Tags: r

I am working with a time series of fish biomass and trying to figure out a way to calculate the time to depletion (biomass change from >1.0 to <0.5) and well as time to recovery (biomass change from <0.5 to >1.0).  I am repeating this for multiple stocks of fish. In some cases there are multiple depletion and recovery events for an individual stock; I would like to calculate the times for all of these events.

```
> dput(head(example))
structure(list(id = c(550L, 558L, 569L, 561L, 572L, 548L), fish = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("cod", "croaker"), class = "factor"), 
year = c(1996L, 1995L, 2000L, 1994L, 1997L, 2001L), biomass = c(1.34, 
1.25, 0.75, 0.61, 0.41, 0.39)), .Names = c("id", "fish", "year", 
"biomass"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> summary.default(example)
    Length Class  Mode   
id      80     -none- numeric
fish    80     factor numeric
year    80     -none- numeric
biomass 80     -none- numeric
```

Comment: sample data doesn't show any change in thresholds as only one value isn't `NA`

Comment: Just removed the NA values, thanks

Comment: What result do you expect from your sample data? I think you want to explain your situation more.

Comment: I am looking for the minimum amount of time in years it takes for biomass to go from at 1.0 to 0.5 and vice versa.  Let me know if you need further details, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a great solution, but it works as I understand your problem with added help from the Twitter conversation [here](https://twitter.com/pofigster/status/949284619786117121).

Because your example data does not include a transition period (would be very helpful to include the period you're trying to detect) I made my own.  Now, I don't include multiple species, so you'll need to split your data.frames out to use the solution here.  I also assume you only measure biomass annually.  This solution requires that your data be sorted by year, otherwise it won't work.

Example data has year and biomass.  I add a new column, `state` and initialize all values as "Stable".

```
example = data.frame(year = 1990:2010,
                     biomass=c(1.7,1.9,1.3,1.5,1.8,1.2,0.9,1.1,
                               1.0,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.8,0.4,
                               0.7,1.1,0.9,1.2,1.4))
example$state = "Stable"
```

Now I want to identify all years that *might* be transition years (<=1.0 or >= 0.5.

```
toCheck = which(example$biomass <= 1 & example$biomass >= 0.5)
```

For each of these years then, I need to determine:

1. Is it really a transition period?  That is, does it start >1 and end <0.5 (or vice versa) or does it just bounce back to where it was?
2. Is it a decline or a recovery?

I use a `while` loop because I need to only consider complete sequences of transition years.  If the biomass goes 1.1->1.0->0.9->1.1, then nothing has happened, it's still stable.  We look at the first case of possible transition and check the preceding value (note, if the first value is a possible transition, this won't work) to determine if we're possibly in a decline or recovery. Then I use subtraction to determine how long the contiguous transition period is. I use this to then determine if the end of the transition indicates an actual decline/recovery or just moving through that space.  If it's real, I change the state to indicate.  Then I remove the contiguous block of transition from `toCheck` and the loop repeats till empty.

```
while(length(toCheck) > 0){
  i = toCheck[1]
  if(example$biomass[i-1] > 1){
    tr = which(`-`(toCheck[-1],i) == 1:(length(toCheck)-1))
    if(example$biomass[length(tr)+1+i] < 0.5) example$state[i:(i+length(tr))] = "Decline"
  } else if(example$biomass[i-1] < 0.5){
    tr = which(`-`(toCheck[-1],i) == 1:(length(toCheck)-1))
    if(example$biomass[length(tr)+1+i] > 1.0) example$state[i:(i+length(tr))] = "Recover"
  }
  toCheck = toCheck[(1:(1+length(tr)))*-1]
}
```

Finally, `rle` calculates run lengths

```
rle(example$state)
#> Run Length Encoding
#>   lengths: int [1:5] 8 2 6 1 4
#>   values : chr [1:5] "Stable" "Decline" "Stable" "Recover" "Stable"
```

I can see then in this sample data that the decline took 2 years (meaning 2 years of being <= 1 and >= 0.5) and the recovery took 1.  It should be trivial to then extract the relevant numbers and aggregate them as needed.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I'll give that a try.  Any idea how you could automate this for ~100 different stocks of fish?

Comment: `l = split(example,example$fish)` will produce a list of data.frames for each stock of fish. Take most of the code in the answer and wrap it in a function, e.g. `f=function(example){...}` then use `lapply(l,f)` and it will apply the function to every stock of fish. You'll have a list of `rle` results which you can then analyze further.

Comment: I tried to 'lapply' to the list, 'l' but am getting this error message: 'Error in if (example$biomass[length(tr) + 1 + i] > 1) example11$state[i:(i +  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'